# Own busybox executable in Android via apk

Tags: android, binary, apk

I need to run my busybox from a Java Android app. To do this, I included a tar archive with busybox in apk res and unpack it to /data/data/com.exeample.test/files with permissions 755. But I can't run it from this location (permisiion denied).
The question arises, how to install binary files through the apk package in general? The question is very interesting due to the very thoughtful security of Android.

I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ready-made binary executables are distributed only inside the apk package in the apk /lib/<ABI> directories (Taken from https://dvelopers.android.com). Otherwise, it will be at least very difficult to execute native code in Android. In the apk package, the /lib/<ABI> directories can contain files with different extensions, this is not limited. In order for the files to be unpacked when installing the apk package, you must set android:extractNativeLibs=true in the manifest (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs).

For Android Studio users, you can create directories

app/src/main/jniLibs/<ABI> - for *.so files

app/src/main/resources/lib/<ABI> - for all other files including *.so.*

then they will be packaged in the /lib/<ABI> directories of the apk package.

From an android application, the path to the native library dir can be obtained by calling getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir.